# Remove the [effect]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/effect) (500+ Questions, 2 Followers) should go. It is not useful on its own. It would sound more useful if combined with other words, like [spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spiral) and [blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blur), resulting in **spiral-effect**, or **blur-effect**, but then those tags already exist.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that it's a vague tag. Questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954333/is-there-possible-to-spiral-effect-on-any-control-in-android definitely need to be retagged. I think [spiral-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spiral-effect) and [blur-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blur-effect) should be used instead of [spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spiral) and [blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blur). [spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spiral) seems to have several definitions based on its questions ranging from the shape to the development methodology. The [blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blur) tag wiki specifies that the tag should be used for the javascript event.

Comment: Considering how noobs (and sometimes even newbies) tag, are you sure it's not used for asking what effect some code/option/... has? Like maybe this r question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781965/interpreting-effect-of-ordered-categorical-predictor

Comment: There are a few like that. I'd say <10% though